# Return a range to compare with BigDecimal

Tags: java, bigdecimal

In my code a user enters in a specified temperature range with this method (The default range is 0 - 100):

```
public class range {   
     public void rangeset ()
      {
        int range1 = 0;
        int range2 = 100;

        System.out.println("Please note that the default temp range is 0-100");
        System.out.println("What is the starting temperature range?");
        range1 = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("What is the ending temperature range?");
        range2 = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Your temperature range is " + range1 + " - " + range2);  

      HW_5.mainMenureturn();

    }//end rangeset method (instance method)

}//range class
```

Further down, I have an input that asks the user for a number that they want to convert to Fahrenheit.

```
public class HW_5 {
   public static double fahrenheit2Centigrade  ()
    {
        double result;
        BigDecimal quotient = new BigDecimal("1.8");


        //take in input, take input as BigDecimal
        System.out.println("Please enter the fahrenheit temperature you wish to convert to celsius");   
        BigDecimal fah = sc.nextBigDecimal();

     }
}
```

So, what I want to do is make sure that the number they entered (which is a BigDecimal) falls within the ranges specified in the other method.

1) How do I get my **rangeset** method to return the beginning number of the range and the ending number of the range since you can't return two values?

2) How do I then use those returned values to check if the BigDecimal in the **fahrenheit2centigrade** method falls within those values?

Please ask for clarification. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue of scope. Currently you are declaring your two range variables inside the rangeset() method, which means that they are only visible within the "scope" of the method (aka only that method has access to those variables).

What you should consider doing is instead have those variables be visible to the entire class.

```
public class range {   
     private int lowerBound;
     private int upperBound;

     public void rangeset ()
      {
        int lowerBound = 0;
        int upperBound = 100;

        System.out.println("Please note that the default temp range is 0-100");
        System.out.println("What is the starting temperature range?");
        lowerBound = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("What is the ending temperature range?");
        upperBound = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Your temperature range is " + range1 + " - " + range2);  

         HW_5.mainMenureturn();

       }//end rangeset method (instance method)

    public int getLowerBound()
    {
        return lowerBound;
    }

    public int getUpperBound()
    {
        return upperBound;
    }

}//range class
```

Once you have things set up in this way, you can create a new `range` class in your main class, call the relevant methods on it, and use your getter methods to extract the data that you care about. Something like:

```
public class HW_5 {
   public static double fahrenheit2Centigrade  ()
    {
        double result;
        BigDecimal quotient = new BigDecimal("1.8");
        range myRange = new range();
        myRange.rangeset();
        System.out.printf("%d - %d", myRange.getLowerBound(), myRange.getUpperBound());


        //take in input, take input as BigDecimal
        System.out.println("Please enter the fahrenheit temperature you wish to convert to celsius");   
        BigDecimal fah = sc.nextBigDecimal();

     }
}
```

Ps. Generally you should use capital letters to start your class names, ie. `Range` instead of `range`.

Comment: The problem is by calling the **rangeset** method from within **fahrenheit2Centrigrade**, you're forcing the user to define the range right within the calculation. I want to just be able to use what they entered in to compare it to the BigDecimal. The problem is that those variables Upper and lowerbound are local.

Comment: They are not local in my answer. You can create the `range` and call `rangeset` anywhere you like. If you create the `range` in a class-wide scope, then all class methods will have access to it.

Comment: Why is it when I create the object from the Range class in the static method fahrenheit2Centrigrade, I get the can't reference it from non-static error but when I create an object from the HW_5 class in a static method, it's fine?

Comment: It's all about scope. This should give you some idea: http://java.about.com/od/s/g/Scope.htm